# Type error: Route "app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts" does not match the required types of a Next.js Route while deploying Next app with NextAuth

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel, netlify, next-auth

I'm deploying my Next App with NextAuth on Vercel but I get this error when uploading my project and I don't understand why! If anyone can help me that would be great!
It perfectly works on my computer.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2vCA.png)

My exports looks like this in [...nextauth] route
[my exports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMGTK.png)

Next and NextAuth versions :
[Next and NextAuth version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ4ZT.png)